# How to use package manager, gopm

Tags: go, package-managers

I am in the process of experimenting with the various package manager offerings on, well, offer for Go.  I like what I read in [gopm](https://github.com/gpmgo/gopm) - simple.  However, thus far I cannot get past the very first hurdle. Here is what I am doing

- Install gopm from source via `go get github.com/gpmgo/gopm`
- Check that it did install. `whereis gopm` returns `/opt/gopkg/bin/gopm`
- For good measure check my environment variables. `echo $GOPATH` returns `/opt/gopkg`.
- Create *main.go* under `/var/www/html/rest`.  The code reads

  package main
  import("github.com/astaxie/beego")

  func main(){
   println("Beego version:beego.VERSION)
  }
- Create the .gopmfile. It reads
  [target]
  path=rest
- Switch to the `/var/www/html/rest` folder. At this point it contains

  root root 20 Jun 25 09:13 .gopmfile
  root root 107 Jun 25 09:13 main.go
- Now issue a `gopm build`. which comes back with
  [GOPM] 15-06-25 09:28:13 [FATAL]: package not installed github.com/astaxie/beego
- Examine the `/var/www/html/rest` folder. It now contains an additional folder `.vendor` which in turn contains the folder `src` which in turn has a symlink to the `/var/www/html/rest` folder.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: i think gopm will not be the regular  package manager for go because `go get` is simple and  friendly enough for people. to use `go get` i suggest, you will get much supports from SO.

Comment: @Jiang Fair point.  However, does that not leave out package version management?

Comment: well, currently a go package is just a set of source code(we strict to pure go, no dynamic libraries wrote in c/c++). so I think version management to the sources is the scope of git, that's why `go get` basically just doing a git clone.

Comment: Like most people, I'm using Mercurial and Git, and I find [Glock](https://github.com/robfig/glock) very effective with these. Gopm seems to be trying to fill a void that doesn't exist: a space without version control systems. That puzzles me.

Comment: After much searching I have more-or-less settled on [Bunch](https://github.com/dkulchenko/bunch). One of the many things I like about it is that it emulates the behavior of NPM - an excellent model to copy.

Comment: The issue I see with a bare bones `go get` approach is that it does not provide any mechanism for discarding unwanted packages and their dependencies. I have seen suggestions to the effect that one should _just delete_ unwanted packages: which has the potential to leave a bunch of non longer needed packages installed as dependencies by the one that just got deleted.

Comment: I use go get this way. set GOPATH to the working directory and then invoke `go get -u`. it will download/update package to your working directory, not globally. less dependency problems i think.

Answer (score -1):

You did not include the dependencies section in your .gopmfile file, which should look something like this:

```
[target]
path = rest

[deps]
github.com/astaxie/beego = tag:v0.9.0
```

Comment: If you are going to down vote you should provide a reason.